# Handle database Journal transaction table with sales and purchase and bank transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, erp

I create a journal transaction table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Finance_Journal_header]
(
    [ID] [NVARCHAR](60) NOT NULL,
    [Header_number] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Header_date] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [nots] [NVARCHAR](4000) NULL,
    [UserID] [NVARCHAR](60)NOT  NULL,
    [isdelete] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [begin_Date] [DATETIME] NOT  NULL,
    [Company_ID] [NVARCHAR](60)  NOT NULL,
    [Last_update] [DATETIME]  NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Finance_Journal_details]
(
    [ID] [NVARCHAR](60) NOT NULL,
    [Header_ID] [NVARCHAR](60) NOT NULL,
    [Account_code] [NVARCHAR](60) NOT NULL,

    [sr] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [nots] [NVARCHAR](4000) NULL,
    [Debit_value] [NUMERIC](14, 3)NOT  NULL,
    [Credit_Value] [NUMERIC](14, 3) NOT NULL,

    [UserID] [NVARCHAR](60)  NOT NULL,
    [isdelete] [BIT] NULL,
    [begin_Date] [DATETIME] NOT  NULL,
    [Company_ID] [NVARCHAR](60)  NOT NULL,
    [Cost_center] [NVARCHAR](60)NOT  NULL,
    [related_doc] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Exchange_Rate] [DECIMAL](18, 2)NOT  NULL,

    [Currency_name] [NVARCHAR](60) NOT NULL,
    [Last_update] [DATETIME] NULL
)
```

I have some other tables for Modules transaction like sales, purchase, bank and treasury transaction

How I can link other modules transaction with GL Journal items?

I have two possible solutions:

1. Create a general view do union select to join any transaction like journal items
2. Fire a trigger to journal items table details in update with any modules change in any table insert or update or delete

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Just no. This is off-topic for many reasons. But before you do anything, start thinking about the actual entities you are modelling. A table with mostly nullable columns is just wrong. One must also know the natural keys, the primary key, and any foreign keys. What you don't do is design backwards from the GL to the actual data that generates your GL.

Comment: This is not full script certainly i already have primary key and foreign keys.. This not my problem now i ask in another thing how i can link another transactions by direct write in journal items s or by create big view union all transaction tables

Comment: What do you mean by link? Do you mean, store a foreign key that allows records to be matched? In every ERP I've seen, you need to explicitly post a batch of transactions in a module to the GL, and that's when you write the transactions to the  GL, including writing a linking key and a batch number. In this situation there is no requirement for a trigger, and in general you should avoid triggers.